# A TextView text scroll turn to the start position when a timer execute RunOnUiThread on Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, timer, xamarin.android

**I have some problem using TextView with android:scrollHorizontally="true" and a timer.

Every time that the timer excute the Elapsed event the text of TextView return in the start position, if the elapsed time is too short the text seams that is tembling.

But when the timer is not running the text scrol properly.

This is the AXML code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:id="@+id/relFullMinimize">
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/minimize_image_button_id"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_gray"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/view_list_image_button_id"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_view_list_dark"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center|top"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/view_list_image_button_id"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/minimize_image_button_id">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/viewplayerfullsongname"
                    android:text="Single-line text view that scrolls automatically if the text is too long to fit in the widget"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/viewplayerfullartistname"
                    android:text="B"
                    android:layout_below="@id/viewplayerfullsongname"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:textColor="#fff1f4f9"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/relFullMinimize"
            android:text="Time xxx"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:focusable="false" />
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/viewplayerProgressBar"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/time"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:focusable="false" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the code ain the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        int count = 1;
        private System.Timers.Timer playerTimer;
        TextView time;
        ProgressBar viewplayerProgressBar;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it
            //Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.myButton);

            //button.Click += delegate { button.Text = $"{count++} clicks!"; };

            FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.viewplayerfullsongname).Selected = true;

            this.playerTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
            this.playerTimer.Elapsed += PlayerTimerHandleElapsed;
            this.playerTimer.Start();

            this.time = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.time);
            this.viewplayerProgressBar = FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.viewplayerProgressBar);
            this.viewplayerProgressBar.Max = 10;

        }

        private void PlayerTimerHandleElapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {

                this.viewplayerProgressBar.IncrementProgressBy(1);
                count++;
                if (count > 100)
                {
                    count = 0;
                }

            RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                this.time.Text = "time: " + count;

            }
            );
        }
```

I think that the problem is about the update of the progressbar and the TextView called "time" using the RunOnUiThred. But if I don't do it the data of that components doesn't refresh.
Someone has some solution?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Every time that the timer excute the Elapsed event the text of TextView return in the start position

Here is your `time`'s layout :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/time"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ...
    />
```

**Solution :**

Change the layout parameter `android:layout_width` from `"wrap_content"` to a fixed width like `"fill_parent"` or `"100dp"`.

[Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xawdT.gif).

**Analysis :**

The problem is that every time when you update the time `TextView` text, the `TextView` will invalidate the entire layout.

Here is the [Source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/TextView.java#TextView.checkForRelayout%28%29) :

```
/**
 * Check whether entirely new text requires a new view layout
 * or merely a new text layout.
 */

private void checkForRelayout() {
    // If we have a fixed width, we can just swap in a new text layout
    // if the text height stays the same or if the view height is fixed.

    if ((mLayoutParams.width != LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ||
            (mMaxWidthMode == mMinWidthMode && mMaxWidth == mMinWidth)) &&
            (mHint == null || mHintLayout != null) &&
            (mRight - mLeft - getCompoundPaddingLeft() - getCompoundPaddingRight() > 0)) {
        // Static width, so try making a new text layout.

        int oldht = mLayout.getHeight();
        int want = mLayout.getWidth();
        int hintWant = mHintLayout == null ? 0 : mHintLayout.getWidth();

        /*
         * No need to bring the text into view, since the size is not
         * changing (unless we do the requestLayout(), in which case it
         * will happen at measure).
         */
        makeNewLayout(want, hintWant, UNKNOWN_BORING, UNKNOWN_BORING,
                      mRight - mLeft - getCompoundPaddingLeft() - getCompoundPaddingRight(),
                      false);

        if (mEllipsize != TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE) {
            // In a fixed-height view, so use our new text layout.
            if (mLayoutParams.height != LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT &&
                mLayoutParams.height != LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT) {
                invalidate();
                return;
            }

            // Dynamic height, but height has stayed the same,
            // so use our new text layout.
            if (mLayout.getHeight() == oldht &&
                (mHintLayout == null || mHintLayout.getHeight() == oldht)) {
                invalidate();
                return;
            }
        }

        // We lose: the height has changed and we have a dynamic height.
        // Request a new view layout using our new text layout.
        requestLayout();
        invalidate();
    } else {
        // Dynamic width, so we have no choice but to request a new
        // view layout with a new text layout.

        nullLayouts();
        requestLayout();
        invalidate();
    }
}
```